# Is it possible to add two nodes at a time dynamically to a treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am having a tree-view on my main form with initially some nodes as follows

```
        ACH
         |-> some.txt
            |->FileHeader
              |->BatchHeader
```

Now at this point i will have to add 2 child nodes at a time to BatchHeader. This nodes i will pass as strings from child forms

My sample code that i added some nodes is as follows

```
  public void loadingDatafrom(string filename, bool str)
    {
        if (Append.oldbatchcontrol != filename)
        {
            if (tvwACH.SelectedNode.Text == "FileHeader")
            {
                tvwACH.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(filename);
            }
            if (tvwACH.SelectedNode.Text == "BatchHeader" && filecontrolvariables.m_gridclick == false)
            {
                tvwACH.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(filename);
               **I got this idea tvwach.SelectedNode.Lastnode.Nodes.Add("Node");**
            }
        }
     }
```

Can any one give an idea to add 2 nodes as child to the existing node ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call the Add method twice, for example:

```
  TreeNode node = tvwACH.SelectedNode;
  node.Nodes.Add(filename);
  node.Nodes.Add("Node");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant you want to add two levels of nodes, try this:

```
TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode("NewNode");
newNode.Nodes.Add("SubNode");
tvwACH.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);
```